# closure in webworker-theads

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

When i was studying worker threads in node.js, I followed the instructions on "webworker-threads" npm package website,  and  I implemented the following code slightly wrong. That made me rethink of closure.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Worker = require("webworker-threads").Worker;
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  //   let counter = 0; // if i put this here code is not working
  const worker = new Worker(function() {
    this.onmessage = function() {
      let counter = 0;
      while (counter < 1000000) {
        counter = counter + 1;
      }
      this.postMessage(counter);
    };
  });
  worker.onmessage = function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  };
  worker.postMessage();
});
app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
  res.send("this is fast");
});
app.listen(3100, () => {
  console.log("listening");
});
```

By mistake I put `let counter=0` outside the worker function but server was hanging and failed to load. Then I put it inside the worker function to try something different and it worked.

But how can I describe this? Is this correct?

Worker function cannot access to its closure.

Also in this example why worker function is not allowed to access to its closure? Because there is only one function who wants to access to 
let counter=0

Comment: Many, varied, and far too broad for a Stackoverflow question.

Comment: In general, almost anywhere you can use a class/constructor you can use a closure instead. In theory, closures and objects are equivalent -  they both maintain states. I believe there is even a paper that proves this but don't quote me on that

Comment: @Quentin I think since my question is on hold, I cannot ask any question for now. How can I resolve this issue? do i have to wait till on hold flag is cancelled. I edited question a few days ago and I added more detail today too it is still on hold.  till when I wont be able to ask questions. I have to ask some urgent questions :(

Comment: The webworker-thread library is a bit weird because **it breaks the concept of closure**. The worker thread API cannot run in the same scope as the rest of your code. Indeed, the original API executes a separate javascript file. The anonymous function thing is a hack. What the API does is convert the function body to a string and treat that as a worker source file - obviously a string is not linked in any way to the memory of the main thread - thus any closure that you want to create like your `counter` does not work

Comment: I would generally avoid such libraries and depend more on concurrency rather than parallelism unless I really-really need it. And when I do use such things I make sure to remember that it does not really work like normal javascript

Comment: so what you are saying is in order to create a closure, both functions should be controlling the same memory part. that;s why we need to create a closure because data is mixing in the memory and memory is going nuts, so that part of  memory cannot differentiate which function invokes itself, it just gives the respond

Comment: and what do u mean by saying "The anonymous function thing is a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Alternative to Object Oriented programming

In theory, anywhere you can use a class/constructor you can use a closure instead. They both essentially perform the same thing: encapsulate data and maintain state - but via different mechanisms. Objects maintain state using context (Java calls it "scope" but because Java does not actually have real scopes) and closures do it using scope.

Closures are especially useful for replacing single-method classes (which surprisingly there are many uses of):

Let's take a simple file logger. An OO implementation could be:

```
class Logger {
    constructor (filename) {
        this.logfile = fs.openSync(filename,'a');
        this.log.bind(this);
    }

    log (txt) {
        const now = new Date().toISOString();
        fs.write(this.logfile, `${now} : ${txt}\n`);
    }
}

// usage:
const logger = new Logger('file.log');
logger.log('Hello');
```

The same logic can be implemented using a closure instead:

```
function makeLogger (filename) {
    const logfile = fs.openSync(filename,'a');

    return function (txt) {
        const now = new Date().toISOString();
        fs.write(logfile, `${now} : ${txt}\n`); // <-- using closure here!
    }
}

// usage:
const log = makeLogger('file.log');
log('Hello');
```

Depending on who you talk to, the closure implementation is easier to read (I'm one of the people who feel more comfortable with closures than classes). It is not only shorter but the state is also contained and cannot be changed from other code.

## 2. Generally anywhere you need a new scope (need to hide something)

Since functions are the ONLY mechanism for manipulating scope you will also need to use closures to create scope. This is especially useful in security critical code such as code dealing with authentication and financial transactions that need to interact with 3rd-party libraries.

#### 2.1. Node modules

Node.js specifically uses closure to implement something that does not exist in javascript: file scope.

Modules in node are loaded inside an IIFE thereby creating a closure. All variables in a module file are visible to all functions defined in the file (closure) but not visible to other modules (unless declared without a `var`, `let` or `const`). Ryan Dahl did not want to modify Javascript as a language but just add a framework on top of the language to make it useful outside browsers. Fortunately Javascript is powerful enough (has closures) that this is possible.

## Real-world examples

There are several real-world examples of large-scale uses of closures:

- `React.FunctionComponent` is a recent feature in React.js that allows users to use a closure to implement React components instead of a class. This often cuts down on lines of code and complexity (yes, this is more front-end related but it is very large scale)
- `async.js` uses closures a lot to keep track of asynchronous operations
- `Express.js` is mixed. While most of the code is OO it also uses closures especially in the middleware/routing architecture.

Comment: Brother looks like you are a node.js professor. I should ask my questions directly to you since others down voting :)

Comment: Is there any good book about node.js or general about javascript you can suggest.

Comment: Good old "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford is still good even though it doesn't cover newer versions of the language (it's written for ES3). Or just search for "Douglas Crockford" on youtube

Comment: I just ordered that book plus his new book "How JavaScript Works". any good source for node.js

Comment: If you are already learning advanced javascript then you don't need any node specific book. Just read the node documentation and get familiar with the provided standard library

Answer (score -1):

A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. And thus **the inner function has access to variables of outer function even after the outer function has returned**.
Now as we come to its applications, we know that node.js doesn't support access specifiers implicitly closures allow us to do that
Below is an example of the same:

```
a = (function () {
  var privatefunction = function () {
    alert('hello');
  }

  return {
    publicfunction : function () {
        privatefunction();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question at all. You are just describing what a closure is, the question says "I know what closure is". It is asking for real-world examples where they are useful.

Comment: That's what the example states! You have to read the complete answer. I explained the closure because of your definition of closure doesn't explain it properly!